# Is there any possibility to view when last request was to a specific folder in IIS website

Tags: web, iis, asp.net-web-api, windows-server-2012

Is there any possibility to view when last request was to a specific folder in IIS website ?

I am sitting here with a website with structure as below,

- Sites

  - Web API Project

    - Files related to web api
    - Test

      - v1
      - vn  (around 20 versions of api)
    - Uat

      - v1
      - vn  (around 20 versions of api)
    - Live

      - v1
      - vn  (around 20 versions of api)
    - v1 ---- vn (around 20 versions of api)

I am new to this place and person who created all these versions has left. There are so many internal or maybe external apps making calls to these api's, I am not sure, is Fiddler my last choice on a production server ? documentation is next to non.

My job is to figure out which api was used last time, so maybe IIS logs, or any other way I could find out, I worked with IIS but not at this level, looking for any clues.

We are using Windows 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can [inspect the IIS logs](https://stackify.com/where-are-iis-log-files-located/) to do this.

The IIS logs are usually located at: `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles`.

To find the correct `W3SVC` in the root log folder, go into IIS and click on Sites. The number in the ID column corresponds to the number in the folder name after `W3SVC` in the log folder.

[image] [image]

Assuming you want to look for requests to the 'Live' folder (and I'm also assuming that it's a virtual directory under the website), you want to look for lines in the IIS log which look like this:

```
[Timestamp] [IP] GET /Live/v1/
```